# In SPE how can we assign dynamic hashtable to Read-variable options for checklist editor

Tags: sitecore-client, powershell-extensions

I have a requirement to show list of options as checklist to user for selection. If followed [In Powershell how to enable/show options like Select All | DeSelect All for Multilist field type](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26825/in-powershell-how-to-enable-show-options-like-select-all-deselect-all-for-mult) , it have static data for checklist then its working fine but when i am having an object whoes value evaluated at runtime then its not working. e.g.

```
$scriptlist=@{}
$scriptitems =  get-childitem '/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library' -recurse | where{$_.templateid -eq '{DD22F1B3-BD87-4DB2-9E7D-F7A496888D43}' } |foreach-object{

$currentscript=$_
$scriptlist.add($currentscript.id.guid,$currentscript.DisplayName)    

}
```

Now i want to show this list as input to user, if i use below code:

```
 
$dialogParams = @{
    Title = "Dialog title"
    Description = "Description under title"
    OkButtonName = "Execute"
    CancelButtonName = "Close"
    ShowHints = $true
    Parameters = @(
         @{
            Name = "checkListSelector"
            Title = "Checklist Selector"
            Editor = "checklist"
            Options = $scriptlist
            Tooltip = "Select one or more options"
        }
    )
}
```

But getting error in logs: [image]

```
$dialogResult = Read-Variable @dialogParams
```

Although i tried to change `(Options = $scriptlist)` with new variable but that also didn't work.

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing ".ToString()" after `.guid`.

```
$currentscript.id.guid.ToString()
```

And you should switch the order most probably, like that:

```
$scriptlist.add($currentscript.DisplayName, $currentscript.id.guid.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks, able to see result now, but still have two issue 1. Currently checklist displays itemid but If i change the order as you suggested, i got error "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary" due to duplicate key name(Due to it i had changed the order but then on UI it shows itemlist). 2.  $scriptlist (or any new variable) not persist selected checkbox list, in other words we need to get list of option selected by user. $checkListOptions = $scriptlist.clone()
........
$dialogResult = Read-Variable @dialogParams

Comment: You should limit posts here to a single question. Create a new one with your further questions.

Comment: sure, accepted the answer

Comment: I got fix for my other two issue as well, 1. i was referring wrong variable to access selected checklist, it should be checkListSelector 2. I have added relative path to keys so that it will be distinct. Now will work on my rest of the script... :)