# Is there a way to add check box to powershell reports to select or unselect the items from report?

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

We have a requirement,to show list of items with checkbox to select or unselect the items. Like this,
[image]

I have tried dialog box with checklist editor by referring to following articles,
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26825/in-powershell-how-to-enable-show-options-like-select-all-deselect-all-for-mult&ved=2ahUKEwjVmqPC-Lv3AhUeTmwGHQ6CAZQQFnoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3ng_EAFTwB9bioGjqOIq_F
but that is not giving the expected result. How can I create a custom list view with checkbox using powershell script?

Comment: If you have time to create a pull request, I can include that functionality in the core product. But you could accomplish something similar without the check boxes. If you create a custom action in the report, you can have it operate on all of the items.

Comment: Hi Michael, the image attached is a UI prototype. How do I create a custom action in the report?Sorry I am a newbie to powershell script. And will I be able to add and remove items from the this report if I click on Add item/Remove selected?

Comment: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/reports/authoring-reports#report-actions

Comment: Thanks Michael, I will have a look into it.